# How do I get log output in test kitchen?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I have this in my recipe:

```rb
log mylog1 do
  level :info
  message 'WHY I NO SEE THIS?'
end
log mylog2 do
  level :info
  message 'WHY I NO SEE THIS?'
end
```

This is what I see when doing `kitchen converge -l debug`:

```
...
Converging 3 resources
Recipe: mybook::myrecipe
  * log[mylog1] action write
  * log[mylog1] action write
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts of this question:

First, The log level passed to kitchen with "-l debug" is for the *kitchen executable* and not for the *provisioner*, in this case "***chef-solo***". Therefore, if you run the kitchen with debug option, you would see that, provisioner is running with ***log_level*** as "***auto***" as below, even when kitchen in debug mode:

```
[SSH] vagrant@127.0.0.1<{:user_known_hosts_file=>"/dev/null",
:paranoid=>false, :port=>"2222", :compression=>false, :compression_level=>0,
:keepalive=>true, :keepalive_interval=>60, :timeout=>15, :keys_only=>true,
:keys=>["/Users/mpriyada/myWorks/.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/kitchen-default-centos/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"],
:auth_methods=>["publickey"], :user=>"vagrant"}> (sh -c 'sudo -E /opt/chef/bin/chef-solo
--config /tmp/kitchen/solo.rb --log_level auto --force-formatter --no-color
--json-attributes /tmp/kitchen/dna.json')
```

Which means that, in chef-solo logging priority, "***auto***" comes par with "***warn***" level. ***And hence no output is logged if log level is set as info in the "log" resource.*** Try below code, you observe the difference:

```
log "mylog1" do
   level :warn
   message 'WHY I NO SEE THIS?'
end

log "mylog2" do
   level :info
   message 'WHY I NO SEE THIS?'
end
```

Output:

```
Recipe: test3::default
   * log[mylog1] action write[2016-08-17T03:55:16+00:00] WARN: WHY I NO SEE THIS?      

   * log[mylog2] action write
Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
```

Now, Second part, if you don't want to run your kitchen in "***auto***" **log_level**, you can go to "***/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.10.0/lib/kitchen/provisioner/chef_base.rb***" and change the **hard coded log level** from ***auto*** to whatever ***chef-solo*** logging permits https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_solo.html.

Comment: Can I set this in .kitchen.yml or a config file somewhere in my cookbook or recipe instead of modifying the actual kitchen code?

Comment: As, Its hard coded. Am afraid as not much can be done.

Comment: kitchen log level can be changed via environment variable: `KITCHEN_LOG='DEBUG' kitchen converge`

Comment: @Duke - Question is to change chef-solo/chef-zero log level change while running kitchen.

Answer (score 4):

Since Kitchen 1.7.0 you can configure this in kitchen.yml:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  log_level: info
```

See [this page](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-docs/blob/master/source/docs/dynamic-configuration.html.md) (doesn't seem to be linked to in the Kitchen docs)

Answer (score 1):

With a newer Kitchen you can also do `kitchen test -D` to trigger debug output for kitchen AND your `chef-client` run.